# Invalid JDK version in profile 'java8-and-higher'

Tags: maven, java

Мавен при инстале дает такую ошибку:

> ```
> Project ID: com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-jpeg2000
>
> Reason: Invalid JDK version in profile 'java8-and-higher': Unbounded 
> range: [1.8, for project com.github.jai-imageio:jai-imageio-jpeg2000
> ```

В проекте стоит jdk 1.7.

pom:

```
<profile>
    <id>java8-and-higher</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
    </activation>
</profile>


<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: В проекте на GitHub https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-jpeg2000/blob/master/pom.xml

В профайле нне закрыта скобка `<jdk>[1.8,</jdk>`. Возможно maven это не понимает.

Comment: да спасибо большое, в этом и была ошибка. открыл этот файл у себя в локальном репозитории, отредактировал его и все заработало.